# Multilingual settings form using i18n variable

Tags: 7, forms, i18n-l10n

I'm using a settings form for my module and I'm trying to make some of the fields multilingual.

I've declared the multilingual variables with hook_variable_variable_info (and with hook_variable_group_info for my custom group):

```
function MYMODULE_variable_info() {
  $variable['my_variable_name'] = array(
    'type' => 'string',
    'title' => t('My title'),
    'default' => MY_DEFAULT_VALUE,
    'description' => t('My description.'),
    'localize' => TRUE,
    'group' => 'my_group'
  );

  return $variable;
}
```

I've added my settings form (one field for example)

```
function MYMODULE_settings_form() {
  $form = array();

  $form['my_variable_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('My title'),
    '#title_display' => 'before',
    '#default_value' => variable_get_value('my_variable_name'),
  );

  return system_settings_form($form); 
}
```

And as you can see I've used system_settings_form($form) to save my form fields as variables.
I've checked my new variable at 'admin/config/regional/i18n/variable' and the form shows that it's a multilingual form and multilingual field, but when I'm switching to another language the value isn't saved. (Only the English version saves and changes the value for all languages)

Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to be that I'm using variable_get_value and not i18n_variable_get, but how do I get the current 'variable_realm_key_language' so I'll know the current language?

Comment: check the global $language variable

Comment: I'll check it again, but I don't think that the variable_realm_key_language is there. Do you?

Comment: No, but if you're looking to use i18n_variable_get($name, $langcode), $langcode is definitely in $language.

Comment: But the langcode shows the current langcode and not the i18n current language (when using variables translation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best solution at all, but one way would be getting the langcode from the url parameters:

```
$langcode = !empty($_GET['variable_realm_key_language']) ? $_GET['variable_realm_key_language'] : $GLOBALS['language']->language;
```

And then you can use i18n_variable_get() using the $langcode as the second parameter.

Comment: This was also my solution as well, but it doesn't feel right.. Still wondering what is the best practice.

Comment: you can call global $language; and use $language->language rather then getting it from url

Answer (score 3):

I was in a need to create translatable strings for text entered using **Page title** module and I used the following code to create variable

```
function module_variable_info($options) {
    $variables['page_title_type_news_and_event'] = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'title' => t('Page title CT New Events', array(), $options),
    'default' => '',
    'description' => t('Module : Page title', array(), $options),
  );

  return $variables;
}
```

Now I can see them in others tab at **admin/config/regional/i18n/variable** and I enabled the check box there

[image]

Then I can translate my string at **admin/config/system/variable** and at **others tab**

[image]